# Jsp is only displaying the headers of my mySQL table not the content of them

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, dao

I'm trying to set up a connection between a database and a Website using JSP, MySQL, Servlets and a DAO. The connection gets established but only the Headers of the table get displayed the data is not. Using IntelliJ Idea as IDE.

The connection gets established but only the headers get displayed the Data does not seem to get transferred as all values are replaced by their defaults.

This is the object Filme, the other attributes do have getter and setters as well trying to shorten though.

```java
package Filme;

public class Film {
    private int idFilme;
    private String Titel;
    private int Laenge;
    private  int Erscheinungsjahr;
    private String Hauptdarsteller;
    private String Produzent;
    private String Studio;
    private String Regiesseur;
    private String Produktionsland;
    private String Cover;
    private String Trailer;

    public int getIdFilme() {
        return idFilme;
    }

    void setIdFilme(int idFilme) {
        this.idFilme = idFilme;
    }

    public String getTitel() {
        return Titel;
    }

    void setTitel(String titel) {
        Titel = titel;
    }



    public int getErscheinungsjahr() {
        return Erscheinungsjahr;
    }

    void setErscheinungsjahr(int erscheinungsjahr) {
        Erscheinungsjahr = erscheinungsjahr;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Film{" +
                "idFilme=" + idFilme +
                ", Titel='" + Titel +
                ", Laenge=" + Laenge +
                ", Erscheinungsjahr=" + Erscheinungsjahr +
                ", Hauptdarsteller='" + Hauptdarsteller  +
                ", Produzent='" + Produzent  +
                ", Studio='" + Studio  +
                ", Regiesseur='" + Regiesseur  +
                ", Produktionsland='" + Produktionsland  +
                ", Cover='" + Cover +
                ", Trailer='" + Trailer +
                '}';
    }
```

This is the Dao for the Film object, which establishes the connection and retrieves the data. For some reason the IDE thinks the import of Filme.Film is unused even though I'm using attributes from the class later on.

```
package Filme;

import Filme.Film;
import java.sql.*;

public class FilmDao {
    public Film getFilm(int idFilme)
    {
        Film a = new Film ();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/filme","root", "root" );
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from filme.filme where idFilme=" + idFilme);
            if (rs.next())
            {
                a.setIdFilme(rs.getInt("idFilme"));
                a.setTitel(rs.getString("Titel"));
                a.setErscheinungsjahr(rs.getInt("Erscheinungsjahr"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

        return a;
    }
}
```

This is the Servlet. Same thing here the Film and FilmDao imports are apparently unused.

```
package Filme;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import Filme.Film;
import Filme.FilmDao;

public class getFilme extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        int idFilme = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idFilme"));
        FilmDao dao=new FilmDao();
        Film a1 = dao.getFilm(idFilme);

        request.setAttribute("Film", a1);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Film_fein.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

The page where the ID of the Film to be displayed is captured. Film_grob.jsp

```
<%@ page import="Filme.Film" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
   <%
       Film a1 = (Film)request.getAttribute("Film");

       out.println(a1);
   %>
</body>
</html>
```

The Page where the Data should get displayed (Film_fein.jsp)

```
<%@ page import="Filme.Film" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
   <%
       Film a1 = (Film)request.getAttribute("Film");

       out.println(a1);
   %>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the output to be the table headers and the table data but only the Headers and default values get displayed.
Thanks in advance for any help you could give me.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I was using the wrong Driver and storing it in the wrong place code is working fine though.

Be sure to add your drivers via maven like a smart person.